# Библиотека для создания графиков

Tags: c#, winforms, graph

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какой элемент в windows forms можно использовать для создания таких графиков? (их там 2 вида(столбчатая и полукруг))
или может есть какие-нибудь библиотеки

Comment: ImageBox. Рисуете в памяти через GDI+ картинку, а затем отображаете ее на ImageBox.

Comment: [Chart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: https://github.com/oxyplot/